# implement striping algorithm C++

Tags: c++, process, ifstream

Hi I am having trouble implementing a striping algorithm. I am also having a problem loading 30000 records in one vector, I tried this, but it is not working.

> The program should declare variables to store ONE RECORD at a time. It should read a record and process it then read another record, and so on. Each process should ignore records that "belong" to another process. This can be done by keeping track of the record count and determining if the current record should be processed or ignored.  For example, if there are 4 processes (numProcs = 4) process 0 should work on records 0, 4, 8, 12, ... (assuming we count from 0) and ignore all the other records in between.`

```
   Residence res;
int numProcs = 4;
int linesNum = 0;
int recCount = 0;
int count = 0;

while(count  <=  numProcs)
{
    while(!residenceFile.eof())
   {
        ++recCount;
      //distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
        if(recCount % processIS  == linesNum)
        {
           residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;
           distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
       }
      ++linesNum;

   }
    ++count;
}
```

Update the code

```
Residence res;
int numProcs = 1;
int recCount = 0;



    while(!residenceFile.eof())
    {
        residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;

        //distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
        if ( recCount == processId)//process id
        {
            distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
        }
        ++recCount;
        if(recCount == processId )
            recCount = 0;
    }
```

update sudo code

```
 while(!residenceFile.eof())
    {
        residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;


        if ( recCount % numProcs == numLines)
        {
            distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
        }
        else
          ++numLines
        ++recCount
    }
```

Comment: The updated code seems confused (and confusing); is `numProcs` the *number of processes*, or the *process ID*?

Comment: jsut I want to see is the updated logic is right ?

Comment: What is your native language?

Comment: @Beta I am really I am tried of jumping around form and stack exchange  I'm really try my best to implement user Answer. I really need to get  is just I want right  Answers

Comment: @Beta I wrote the all program by myself but I really need this part to make it work right I can post the code if you want ?

Comment: In my answer I try to explain the way to reach the final code. I do not give the final code. Maybe I seem unhelpful, but truly I want to help you. I believe that if I try to give you the code, it will fail because of some small miscommunication. I have written C++ for many years, and I believe that the steps I describe are the fastest way to good code. Please try them, and tell me where you have trouble. *If you try to write the final code without first mastering the basic elements, you will probably fail.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your post with MPI, but I don't see any place where you are checking a processor ID to see which record it should process.

Pseudocode for a solution to *what I think* you're asking:

```
While(there are more records){
If record count % numProcs == myID
   ProcessRecord
else
   Increment file stream pointer forward one record without processing
Increment Record Count
}
```

If you know the # of records you will be processing beforehand, then you can come up with a cleverer solution to move the filestream pointer ahead by `numprocs` records until that # is reached or surpassed.

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper: You will only ever process `numProcs` records in the updated code. Note the modulus operator `%` in my pseudocode. Familiarize yourself with modulo math, it'll be useful to you as a developer.

Comment: thanks for Pseudocode "shoud file stream pointer forward one record without processing" be something like line number

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper: Well, you will need a way of skipping the data for the record you don't want to process. If you know that it's just going to be 2 ints, you could just read in 2 ints and throw them away. If you know it's going to be some line, call a `getline` and then do nothing with the string you read into. From the look of it, you are already reading in `res.x` and `res.y`, so that's probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A process that will act on records 0 and 4 must still *read* records 1, 2 and 3 (in order to get to 4).

Also, `while(!residenceFile.eof())` isn't a good way to iterate through a file; it will read one round past the end. Do something like `while(residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y)` instead.

As for making a vector that contains 30,000 records, it sounds like a memory limitation. Are you sure you need that many in memory at once?

**EDIT:**

Look carefully at the updated code. If the process ID (`numProcs`) is zero, the process will act on the first record and no other; if it is something else, it will act on *none* of them.

**EDIT:**

Alas, I do not know Arabic. I will try to explain clearly in English.

You must learn a simple technique, before you attempt a difficult technique. If you *guess* at the algorithm, you will fail.

First, write a loop that iterates {0,1,2,3,...} and prints out all of the numbers:

```
int i=0;
while(i<10)
{
  cout << i << endl;
  ++i;
}
```

**Understand this before going farther.** Then write a loop that iterates the same way, but prints out only {0,4,8,...}:

```
int i=0;
while(i<10)
{
  if(i%4==0)
    cout << i << endl;
  ++i;
}
```

**Understand this before going farther.** Then write a loop that prints out only {1,5,9,...}. Then write a loop that reads the file, and reports on every record. Then combine that with the logic from the previous exercise, and report on only one record out of every four.

**Start with something small and simple. Add complexity in small measures. Develop new techniques in isolation. Test every step. Never add to code that doesn't work.** This is the way to write code that works.

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper: All right, I'll try to give you code. Just one question first: are you sure you know how to give each process a process ID from {0,1,2,3}?